# Comparison of Shear Stress obtained from thin-walled beam theory and Timoshenko beam theory

Tags: beam

I am studying the book "Structural Analysis with Applications to Aerospace Structures" by Craig. In Chapter 8 titled "Thin-Walled Beams", the authors derived the governing differential equation

$$ \frac{\partial n}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = 0 $$

where, $n$ is the axial flow, $f$ is shear flow, $x_1$ is axial coordinate, and $s$ is curvilinear coordinate along cross-section.

Substituting $n = \sigma_{xx} \times t(s)$, and $\sigma_{xx}$ from Euler-Bernoulli Beam theory, we have

$$ f = c + \frac{Q_3(s)H_{23}^c - Q_2(s)H_{33}^c}{H_{22}^c H_{33}^c - H_{23}^c H_{23}^c} V_3 - \frac{Q_3(s)H_{22}^c - Q_2(s)H_{23}^c}{H_{22}^c H_{33}^c - H_{23}^c H_{23}^c} V_2$$

with

$Q_2 = \int E x_3 t ds$ and $Q_3 = \int E x_2 t ds$.

where, $c$ is an arbitrary constant which is zero at open end of cross-sections, $H_{ij}^c$ are centriodal bending stiffnesses, $V_i$ are shear forces.

Another way to determine shear stress in a beam cross-section is to use Timoshenko beam theory.

Question: What are the difference between the shear stresses obtained from the two methods? Do both approach capture the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timoshenko%E2%80%93Ehrenfest_beam_theory) (emphasis mine):

> The Timoshenko–Ehrenfest beam theory was developed by Stephen Timoshenko and Paul Ehrenfest early in the 20th century. **The model takes into account shear deformation and rotational bending effects**, making it suitable for describing the behaviour of thick beams, sandwich composite beams, or beams subject to high-frequency excitation when the wavelength approaches the thickness of the beam. The resulting equation is of 4th order but, unlike Euler–Bernoulli beam theory, there is also a second-order partial derivative present. Physically, taking into account the added mechanisms of deformation effectively lowers the stiffness of the beam, while the result is a larger deflection under a static load and lower predicted eigenfrequencies for a given set of boundary conditions.

The inclusion of shear deformation and rotational bending effects being the main difference between the Timoshenko beam and Euler–Bernoulli beam. But I don't think there is a difference between the two models in the derivation of the shear stresses.

Comment: Dear, thank you for you reply. The question is not about the difference between Euler-Bernoulli and Timoshenko, rather thin-walled beams (as described in the book) and Timoshenko beam theories.

Comment: You can read Mechanics of Materials (Timoshenko & Gere) Ch 9.6 - Shear Stress in Beams of Thin-Walled Open Cross Section. The shear stress tau = VQ/It, and shear flow f = tau*t = VQ/I. Is this you wanted to compare?

Comment: Shear flow can be divided by wall thickness to obtain shear stresses. The shear flows are obtained using theory of thin-walled beams (Please correct me if I am wrong). Another way to obtain shear stresses in a beam is to use Timoshenko beam theory. What are the differences between these two shear stresses? What are the similarities and differences between these two?

Comment: Note that the shear formula above was derived from beam theory, For thin-walled profiles, the shear distribution through thickness can be ignored, thus the "t" is dropped out from the shear formula. The textbook I mentioned is available in many libraries, if you are in the US, that you can borrow and read.

Comment: @AliBaig the difference is how the two approximations handle the boundary conditions on the stress distribution in the complete structure. (Note, both approximations make assumptions that are not necessarily correct!)